# Function argument continuation

Tags: c++, clang-format

I was looking over the [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and I cannot find if there is an option for the following. If a function and its arguments break the `ColumnLimit` I'd like to continue the arguments on new lines.

```
// Good
SomeLongFunction(first_argument,
                 second_argument,
                 third_argument,
                 fourth_argument,
                 fifth_argument);

// Bad
SomeLongFunction(first_argument, second_argument, third_argument,
                 fourth_argument, fifth_argument);
```

It looks like `AlignAfterOpenBracket` will at least let me configure where to indent when it decides to continue to the next line, but I can't find something that let's me specify to break the arguments up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want:

```
BinPackParameters: false
```

With this, your bad example is formatted into the good example. The documentation:

> BinPackParameters (bool)
>
> If false, a function declaration’s or function definition’s parameters
>   will either all be on the same line or will have one line each.
>
> ```
> true:
> void f(int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
>        int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) {}
>
> false:
> void f(int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
>        int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
>        int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) {}
> ```

Additionally:

```
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

may be useful if you prefer to break all arguments even if they would fit on single line after a single break. Documentation:

> AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine (bool)
>
> If the function declaration doesn’t fit on a line, allow putting all parameters of a function declaration onto the next line even if
>   BinPackParameters is false.
>
> ```
> true:
> void myFunction(
>     int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
>
> false:
> void myFunction(int a,
>                 int b,
>                 int c,
>                 int d,
>                 int e);
> ```